# rescue aws s3 exception in rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to rescue an aws s3 exception.

```
class FileManager
  def fetchFile
    begin
      s3.get_object(bucket:'myBucket', key: file_name)
    rescue Aws::S3::Errors => e
      debugger
    end
  end
 end
```

Then when I call the method from console

```
FileManager.fetch_file('Non existing file')
```

I am not getting the debugger instead there is an error message in the console

```
Aws::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rescue all S3 errors using `ServiceError`

```
begin
  # ...
rescue Aws::S3::Errors::ServiceError => e
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has what your looking for (assuming you are using this gem):

https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3#when-things-go-wrong